# Getting data from Kobo Toolbox

Tags: rest, curl

I want to get my form data back from kobo api (https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/). I registered client application from kobo. To authorize client application, i run below url but it results in

```
http://localhost/kobo/o/authorize?client_id=MY_CLIENT_iD&response_type=code&state=xyz
```

---

Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.9

---

Similarly request for access token also result in same error

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/o/token/");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=authorization_code&\ncode=PSwrMilnJESZVFfFsyEmEukNv0sGZ8&\nclient_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&\nredirect_uri=http://localhost:30000");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "USERNAME" . ":" . "PASSWORD");


$headers = array();

$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close ($ch);
```

---

Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.9

---

I am using xampp and curl is enabled.

Comment: Did you ever get it working? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/  not https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/

checkout docs here http://help.kobotoolbox.org/managing-your-project-s-data/rest-services

***MY WORKING CODE:***

```
        $url = 'https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/stats';

    $data = array (
       // 'q' => 'nokia'
        );

        $params = '';
    foreach($data as $key=>$value)
                $params .= $key.'='.$value.'&';

        $params = trim($params, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'?'.$params ); //Url together with parameters
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT , 7); //Timeout after 7 seconds
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER  , false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $header = array();
    $header[] = 'Content-length: 0';
    $header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
    $header[] = 'Authorization: Token xxxxxxxx';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "USERNAME" . ":" . "PASSWORD");

        $result = curl_exec($ch);


if(curl_errno($ch))  //catch if curl error exists and show it
  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);

  echo $result;
```